# Autocomplete popup menu for search results

Tags: search

Autocomplete in insert mode (via `<c-n>`/`<c-p>`) is excellent, in particular the navigable popup box.

I would like the same navigable popup box when I search: so, I type `/`, then start to type, press something, see a list of selectable matches, select one and jump to that location.

Is this possible without a plugin?

Comment: Hi and welcome! This is not the intended usage of the completion list and would probably quite tricky to implement. However, [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim) provides a `:Lines` command which makes it easy to jump to lines matching your search (fuzzy). That's the closer I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you're supposed to do "incremental search" instead. It works like follows: you do `:set incsearch` and then Vim starts moving the cursor while you're typing `/pattern` without awaiting for "enter" hit.

If you really need to browse through previous search patterns, you can make use of `:h cmdwin`. Just press <kbd>Ctrl-F</kbd> (or whatever is the value of `:set cedit?`), or even open search prompt with <kbd>q</kbd><kbd>/</kbd> instead of <kbd>/</kbd>. The you'll get into `:h cmdwin` where you can browse all your previous search patterns. Note that it's a "window" not "menu", so you can search through searches with "/" or "?" as needed.

Comment: Thanks. The `cmdwin` may be useful.

`incsearch` isn't great for my case, because i want to quickly see a list of possibilities--like an overview--then choose, rather than search those all the searches until I find the one I want.

Comment: For all "list of possibilities" maybe use `:g/` instead of `/`?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer my question, but I thought it may enlighten others.

The reasons I wanted this fast-search-with-autocomplete-box was to quickly and repeatedly switch between and edit parts of a file.

I subsequently learnt to use window splits. I now quickly and repeatedly edit different parts of a file using window splits; edit one part, `ctrl w w`, edit the other, repeat.